# SQL Executing Stored Procedures based on conditional logic - How do I have paramaters in the Procedure as the checks for the conditon?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have the following statement below:

```
if dbo.TableExists('table') = 1 
and dbo.columnexists('table', 'column') = 1
BEGIN
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'MS_Description', @value = N'someString',
@level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = 'dbo',
@level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = 'table',
@level2type = N'COLUMN',  @level2name = 'column';
END
```

This should effectively only execute the stored procedure based on if the table exists and the column exists; this code is called from a C# application that programmatically passes through the variables in the stored procedure through string formatting etcetera.

I only want this procedure to run on the condition that the table and the column having an extended property added to it both exist.

However, the parameters being passed through to TableExists() and columnexists() only exist in the scope of the procedure, I believe, which is obviously executed after the condition. My question is, how can I pass through the values in '@level1name' and '@level2name' as the checks?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I got around my issue by declaring my own variables beforehand, so:

```
DECLARE @metaName varchar(128)
SET @metaName = N'MS_Description'

IF (@metaName = 'value')
EXEC ...
@name = @metaName
```

Repeat for all variables as necessary.

Hope that helps someone out in the future.